# ASP.NET using return RedirectToAction(" ", " ") how to use this to redirect to a cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I can not find a useable tutorial that explains how to redirect using REdirectToAction. can someone share a link that that explains ALL the steps needed to use this? I think I am having a hard time understanding how the parameters are given can find an HTML file with a model in the parameter? or is it a controller? I am very lost on how they communicate. please someone if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the RedirectToAction method, you could check the [ControllerBase.RedirectToAction Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-5.0). This method is used to redirect to the specified action according to the action name.

For example: If the Home controller contain the following methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ProductIndex(int id)
{
    var product = RetrieveProduct(id);
    return View(product);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Product(int id, Product product)
{
    UpdateProduct(product);
    return RedirectToAction("ProductIndex","Home", new {id=101}); //the parameters: actionName, controllerName, and routeValues.
}
```

By using the above code, when calling the Product action method, it will redirect to the ProductIndex action method, and send id parameter.

If you want to redirect to a special view, you could use the [View() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

For example, using the following code, if calling the Test method, it will return the Privacy.cshtml view page, and send the Student Object to the view.

```
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        var student = new Student()
        {
            StudentId = 1001,
            StudentName = "Tom"
        };
        return View("~/Views/Home/Privacy.cshtml", student);
    }
```

Code in the Privacy.cshtml:

```
@model netcore5.Models.Student
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="StudentId" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="StudentId" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="StudentName" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="StudentName" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

The output as below:

[image]

Besides, you could also use ViewBag or ViewData to transfer data from the controller to the View page.

More detail information, please refer the following articles:

[Views in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Difference Between return View(), return Redirect(), return RedirectToAction() And RedirectToRoute() In MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-return-view-return-redirect-return-redirecttoaction-and-redirecttoroute-in-mvc)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering you cleared up a lot of my confusion so far with that example. But I'm still confused on the model part of this the view still needs a model to redirect right? what would that look like?

Comment: Please check [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#passing-data-to-views), as we all known, we could pass data to the views using several approaches: Strongly typed data(viewmodel); Weakly typed data (ViewData and ViewBag). If we are using Strongly typed data method, in the .cshtml view page, we could specify a model using the `@model` directive, in this scenario, when we return the view page, we have to return the model from the controller. If the view page doesn't require model, there is no need to return data from the controller.

Comment: About the RedirectToAction method, it also provides the method to transfer model data to another action, if you don't want to transfer data between action method, there is no need to add the model. Check the constructor of the [ControllerBase.RedirectToAction Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Besides, for the [View() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnetcore-5.0), you could also check the constructor method.